# Github "Failed to push some refs"

Tags: git, github

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMm0p.png)

I get this error trying to upload a project on github for the first time. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are committing files without adding so before you type git commit you should first add that file calisma.py and then try git commit command:

To add file you should type below:

```
git add calisma.py
```

and then follow other commands that you are trying as below:

```
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin <Github Repo>
git push -u origin master
```

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the inconsistency between the remote library and the local library, so you can synchronize the remote library to the local library.
Use command:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

And then

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below commands, those worked for me

```
git init
git add .
git config --global user.email "Your Email"
git config --global user.name "Your Name or Username"
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push
```